# git pull in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-git-deployment

When working with the regular source code, (Java, C++, etc..) there are things like

```
git pull ..
git fetch .. 
git push ..
```

to synch your remote git repo branch with your local branch.
What is the equivalent of such in the Azure Data Factory world ?

So, I am using azure data factory with the Azure git repo.
I am working in the particular feature branch - "fefature branch"
And my pipeline has a copy activity that hits a data set in its "Sink" stage.
Here is a screen shot but .. it's pretty simple and seems right

[image]

I see that my code for Data set definition (Json) in the remote Git repository is different from what I see in the Azure portal gui (being pointed to that same remote branch).  ADF Gui in the Azure Portal is correct, the one in the git repo contains some stuff that I already deleted, but it does not gets deleted there (Why??)
So, when I 'Debug' pipeline I get errors which indicate this discrepancy as a problem.  I want ty sync the environments and .. given that **I do not understand** how the discrepancies came about, I don't know how to fix an issue?. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ADF world, we use publish and create a new pull request to merge the new changes from a feature branch to the main branch.

it seems like your git repository version is not up to date with the live ADF.

If there are any pending changes in your main branch, then you can click on Publish button to merge the changes

And if you are working on the feature branches, you can merge the changes using the new pull request.

If you have multiple feature branches, then you will need to manually compare the different versions to resolve these conflicts.

[image: ADF]